# Error on sudo apt-get upgrade and MySQL start job failed

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to start mysql on linux but i'm getting the job failed error. I'm trying to upgrade it just to check if it will fix the issue..

I get the following output when I do sudo apt-get upgrade:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libldb1 libsmbclient linux-generic-lts-utopic
  linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic linux-image-generic-lts-utopic python-ldb
  python-samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-libs smbclient
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                         Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I try to start Mysql i used the following commands:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Output is:

```
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                 [fail]
```

I also tried

```
sudo service mysql start
```

output was:

```
start: Job failed to start
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this? or just any fix on how I can start mysql on our linux server?

This is from the mysql error log

```
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 346701 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x20)[0x7fae3a6bb390]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3d5)[0x7fae3a5a4785]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340)[0x7fae39310340]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x641c1b)[0x7fae3a809c1b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x642fdc)[0x7fae3a80afdc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6306c0)[0x7fae3a7f86c0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x631fc4)[0x7fae3a7f9fc4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5d434a)[0x7fae3a79c34a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6011d9)[0x7fae3a7c91d9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x591958)[0x7fae3a759958]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8182)[0x7fae39308182]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fae38a2247d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
160429  9:59:12 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160429  9:59:12 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160429  9:59:12 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160429  9:59:12 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160429  9:59:12 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160429  9:59:12 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160429  9:59:12 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160429  9:59:12 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160429  9:59:12 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 31469822477
160429  9:59:12  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 31469834088
InnoDB: 2 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 2 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 3A38F00
160429  9:59:12  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 16:59:12 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 346701 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x20)[0x7f0132c33390]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3d5)[0x7f0132b1c785]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340)[0x7f0131888340]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x641c1b)[0x7f0132d81c1b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x642fdc)[0x7f0132d82fdc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6306c0)[0x7f0132d706c0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x631fc4)[0x7f0132d71fc4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5d434a)[0x7f0132d1434a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6011d9)[0x7f0132d411d9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x591958)[0x7f0132cd1958]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8182)[0x7f0131880182]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f0130f9a47d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
160429  9:59:13 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160429  9:59:13 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160429  9:59:13 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160429  9:59:13 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160429  9:59:13 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160429  9:59:13 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160429  9:59:13 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160429  9:59:13 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160429  9:59:13 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 31469822477
160429  9:59:13  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 31469834088
InnoDB: 2 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 2 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 3A38F00
160429  9:59:13  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 16:59:13 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 346701 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x20)[0x7fbdaa413390]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3d5)[0x7fbdaa2fc785]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340)[0x7fbda9068340]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x641c1b)[0x7fbdaa561c1b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x642fdc)[0x7fbdaa562fdc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6306c0)[0x7fbdaa5506c0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x631fc4)[0x7fbdaa551fc4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5d434a)[0x7fbdaa4f434a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6011d9)[0x7fbdaa5211d9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x591958)[0x7fbdaa4b1958]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8182)[0x7fbda9060182]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fbda877a47d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
160429  9:59:14 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160429  9:59:14 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160429  9:59:14 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160429  9:59:14 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160429  9:59:14 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160429  9:59:14 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160429  9:59:14 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160429  9:59:14 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160429  9:59:14 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 31469822477
160429  9:59:14  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 31469834088
InnoDB: 2 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 2 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 3A38F00
160429  9:59:14  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 16:59:14 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 346701 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x20)[0x7f7d40f1b390]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3d5)[0x7f7d40e04785]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340)[0x7f7d3fb70340]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x641c1b)[0x7f7d41069c1b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x642fdc)[0x7f7d4106afdc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6306c0)[0x7f7d410586c0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x631fc4)[0x7f7d41059fc4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5d434a)[0x7f7d40ffc34a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6011d9)[0x7f7d410291d9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x591958)[0x7f7d40fb9958]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8182)[0x7f7d3fb68182]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f7d3f28247d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Comment: have you tried sudo apt-get install -f  looks like there is some dependency problem .. maybe a broken package ... I believe that's the command lol but I'm usually lazy and open synaptic and click on the edit menu then click fix broken packages  :D

Comment: what happens when you try to start the MySQL server? What errors? If you can update your post with that information it may help others understand the problem better.

Comment: @JohnOrion i updated my post and included the errors I get when I try to start msyql

Comment: could  you try starting the server then after it fails run systemctl status mysql.service  > ~/Desktop/output.txt and add the output from your desktop to the list .. that would give more information .. the text added doesn't really show the reason for the failure ... you could also check journalctl -xe > ~/Desktop/output2.txt to see if there is anything about MySQL there . Maybe this will help us point in the right direction to proceed.

Comment: @JohnOrion after i tried to start the server I tried to run `systemctl status mysql.service > ~/Desktop/output.txt` but i got an error that the command was not found

Comment: do you have a /var/log/mysql/error.log? If so could you add  the last bit of it .. or if you could .. note the time .. try to start mysql again .. then check the error log and print out what it shows just in the recent time.

Comment: @JohnOrion i updated the description. i hope that helps

Comment: unfortunately, the errors I see, I don't really understand. The only thing I would probably try would be to make a copy of your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to my.cnf.bak and see if you can find a default one  I have a my.cnf.dpkg in mine to compare. Then modify my.cnf and remove any entries that aren't in the default. Something may have changed and the change is throwing an error ... hard to say. If it doesn't allow you to start mysql  then you can just restore your old my.cnf and sorry to say I can't really help at this point but the information with the logs may help others figure it out